# Can I make an ectoplasmic weapon using Ectoplasmic Spell with Fabricate?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

### [Ectoplasmic Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/ectoplasmic-spell-metamagic/):

> An ectoplasmic spell has full effect against incorporeal or ethereal creatures.

### [Fabricate](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fabricate/):

> You convert material of one sort into a product that is of the same material. Creatures or magic items cannot be created or transmuted by the fabricate spell. The quality of items made by this spell is commensurate with the quality of material used as the basis for the new fabrication. If you work with a mineral, the target is reduced to 1 cubic foot per level instead of 10 cubic feet.
>
> You must make an appropriate Craft check to fabricate articles requiring a high degree of craftsmanship.
>
> Casting requires 1 round per 10 cubic feet of material to be affected by the spell.

Can you use these two to make weapons that effectively have ghost touch, or other objects with what is effectively ghost touch?

Example:
Using an Ectoplasmic Fabricate to make a longsword,  since the longsword is an effect of the spell Fabricate, it has full effect against incorporeal or ethereal creatures.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Rather an ectoplasmic fabricate, not one using components from another ecotplasmic spell.

Comment: Personally, I think an interesting take would be to allow an incorporeal longsword... and leave the question of *how to wield an incorporeal longsword* up to the player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, you cannot

The [Ectoplasmic Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/ectoplasmic-spell-metamagic/) effect is talking about an [Incorporeal](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Incorporeal) creature ability to be immune to non-force spells, as described under the [Incorporeal Special Ability:](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#TOC-Incorporeal-Ex-)

> It is immune to all nonmagical attack forms. Even when hit by spells or magic weapons, it takes only **half damage from a corporeal source** (except for channel energy). Although it is not a magical attack, holy water can affect incorporeal undead. Corporeal spells and effects that do not cause damage only have a **50% chance of affecting an incorporeal creature**. Force spells and effects, such as from a magic missile, affect an incorporeal creature normally.

A "corporeal source" here is talking about corporeal creatures (like Bob the wizard) casting damaging spells against an incorporeal creature. Not only that, but every other spell, other than force spells, have a flat 50% chance of not working at all.

Using the metamagic feat, you ignore that 50% resistance and will affect an incorporeal creature normally. While whatever is created by [Fabricate](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fabricate/) (like a sword) could be used to harm another creature, the spell does not target creatures, and as such, is not a valid spell for [Ectoplasmic Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/ectoplasmic-spell-metamagic/).

But if there is any material that could be forged into incorporeality, it could be created using *Fabricate*. Something like the [Ghost Syrup](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison/#Ghost_Syrup) poison, for instance, which will make a creature that takes full strength damage to become incorporeal permanently. But as far as I know, there is no such item in the game.

Answer (score 6):

**No**

Fabricate spell makes something out of a material. (AKA has an effect on material)

> You convert material of one sort into a product that is of the same material.

While ectoplasmic spell makes the spell have full effect on **creatures** that are incorporeal or ethereal.

> An ectoplasmic spell has full effect against incorporeal or ethereal creatures.

As the materials themselves are not creatures ectoplasmic spell metamagic will have no effect on them as they are not a valid target for ectoplasmic spell metamagic to function on.